# Prove that if W is an initial segment of X×Y then there exists an initial segment V in Y such that X×V is an initial segment of X×Y containing W

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification, set-theory, order-theory, well-orders

Given a ordered set $(X,\preceq)$ for any $\xi\in X$ we call the set
$$
I_\xi:=\{x\in X:x⪱\xi\}
$$
the initial segment of $\xi$.

Now if $(X,\preceq)$ and $(Y,\precsim)$ are two ordered sets then it is a well know result that the proposition
$$
(x_1,y_1)\precapprox(x_2,y_2)\Leftrightarrow(y_1\precnsim y_2)\vee(x_1\preceq x_2\wedge y_1=y_2)
$$
define a order on $X\times Y$ called horizontal lexicographic order.

So provided that $X$ and $Y$ are well ordered in my text is written that if $W$ is an initial segment of $(X\times Y,\precapprox)$ then there exists an initial segment $V$ in $Y$ such that $X\times V$ is an initial segment in $X\times Y$ containing $W$ however I was not able to prove this so that I thought to put a specific question where I ask to prove it.

In particular I tried to use the following result

> A subset $W$ of $X\times Y$ is an initial segment if and only if there exist an initial segment $U$ of $X$ and an initial segment $V$ of $Y$ such that
> $$
> W=X\times V\cup U\times\{u\}
> $$
> where $u$ is the minimum of $Y\setminus V$.

So clearly
$$
W\subseteq X\times V\cup X\times\{u\}=X\times (V\cup\{u\})
$$
but unfortunately $V\cup\{u\}$ is not an inital segment. Anyway if $Y$ has not a maximum element then the set
$$
Y:=\{y\in Y:u\precnsim y\}
$$
is not empty so that it has an element $\eta$ and any initial segment $E$ of $\eta$ contains $V\cup\{u\}$ so that $X\times E$ would be an initial segment of $X\times Y$ such that
$$
W\subseteq X\times E
$$
However if $Y$ has a maximum element then it seem to me that the result does not holds.

So how prove the result? could it be not generally true? could someone help me, please?